# How to get the resize event of a parent window using its handle in child window?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have made Browser window using mfc.
Then added it as a child of VLC player using [SetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
I have the handle of VLC player in my child process.

Now I want to resize the child window (browser) when the VLC window is resized.

Is there any way I can get the resize event of Parent window using its handle in the child code, so I can resize the child dialog as well ?

Comment: Been a while since I used the Windows SDK, but can you not replace the window proc (storing the old one) catching WM_SIZE, then delegating back to the original WndProc either before or after you have handled it yourself?

Comment: message proc doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Using the SetParent() hack is *very* troublesome.  You'd need to write a DLL that can be injected into VLC with SetWindowsHookEx() so you can spy on the messages.  Very hard to get right.  Don't do it, create a plug-in instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking this the wrong way around.

Capture the event in the VLC window and in the handler set the new size for the child (browser) window.

Comment: I dont have much control over vlc. It will just launch my (child) exe.

Comment: Then subclass the parent handle, this routes messages through the new windows object and handle it there. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wt95892.aspx)

Comment: @Oakdale You can't "subclass" across processes!

Comment: @manuell Quite right - I missed that in the question, looks like he's stuffed to me.